# Getting error while using numba. I am using two for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numba

I am using two for loop. To speed up I am trying to use numba. But my function contains pandas data frame.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def Rand_Index(X,Y):How to get rid of this error.
    unique_label_X=np.unique(X['label'])
    unique_label_Y=np.unique(Y['label'])
    n=len(unique_label_X)
    m=len(unique_label_Y)
    matrix=np.zeros((n,m))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            matrix[i,j]=len(pd.merge(X[X['label']==i], Y[Y['label']==j], how='inner', on=['license']))
        #print(pd.merge(X[X['label']==i], Y[Y['label']==j], how='inner', on=['license']))
    
    matrix=matrix.astype(int)
    n_i=np.sum(matrix,axis=1)
    n_j=np.sum(matrix,axis=0)
    sum_n_ij=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            sum_n_ij+=comb(matrix[i,j],2)
            
    b=0
    for j in range(len(n_j)):
        b+=comb(n_j[j],2)

    b=b-sum_n_ij
    
    c=0
    for i in range(len(n_i)):
        c+=comb(n_i[i],2)

    c=c-sum_n_ij
    
    d=comb(np.sum(n_i),2)-(1/2)*(np.sum(n_i**2) + np.sum(n_j**2))
    
    a=sum_n_ij
    
    R=(a+d)/(a+b+c+d)
    
    return R
```

error:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'comb': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

File "../../tmp/ipykernel_18613/1845007483.py", line 21:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?> 

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
- argument 1: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How to get rid of this error. Or suggest how to speed up my function if there is any alternate way

Comment: Numba library will work on  numpy arrays so make sure that whatever data you are providing it should be in the form of np.arrays

Comment: @MdTausif This is not exact: Numba support typed lists, typed dicts and strings for example though they need some conversion. Using Numpy is strongly recommanded but not mandatory.

Comment: @SegmentationFault Consider reading the doc as it explicitly mention Numba: https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/enhancingperf/enhancingperf2.html . Many other page are pretty clear about this. Besides, please provide a minimal reproducible example. The input is missing. This is mandatory since typing is critical in Numba.